# Opera-only bug: CSS hover menus leftover repaint bug - workaround?

Tags: hover, opera, repaint, css

This bug happens only in Opera and in the newest, as well as older, versions. Would appreciate some sort of workaround it.

To reproduce

1. Go to http://colnect.com/en/forum/index!
2. Hover over the "Categories" button on the top left of the screen.
   [image: The menu pops up well]
3. See the "leftovers" from the bottom of the menu (as in attached picture).
   [image: See the "leftovers" from the menu]

This does NOT happen on IE/Chrome/FireFox.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you hover over the dropdown, the whole page scrolls up by a few pixels. Not sure why. Edit: oh wait, that is only the case on the 404 page, not on the page you're supposed to end up on. And it's not the cause of the problem, because the actual page has the problem too. Hm.

Comment: It tested fine for me, Opera 12.14 on openSUSE 12.3.

Comment: @MaKR It has the OP's problem for me in Opera 12.16 both in Windows and Mint.

Comment: Wellp I was wrong, found it on 2nd look.  Googling "opera hide element artifacts" shows nothing relevant.  It seems to me this might be out of your control due to it being the rendering engine.Hopefully I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the bug. Truth is it didn't exist until a few days ago so some changes to the CSS did make Opera react this way. Problem is it was a big change and I have no idea which part would trigger it. I tried to search for such problems reports and found nothing, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to resolve this problem...

Add the below css:

```
ul#top li#categories{position:relative;}

ul#top li ul{top:20px;}
```

It works perfectly in all browsers including Opera.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this CSS tackles the problem above?

Comment: because the "ul#top li ul" have absolute position so we have to define its parent element position to "relative" otherwise it create problem in some browse like opera.

Comment: Adding the position:relative; was sufficient. Thank you very much for your workaround :)